# Сравнение указателей

Tags: c++

Почему в следующем коде

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* a = (char*)"string";
    char* b = (char*)"string";

    if (a == b) std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

При сравнении мы получаем положительный результат? По идеи, мы сравниваем указатели, разве не так?

Но если объявить массив, то все должно правильно работать

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char a[] = "string";
    char b[] = "string";

    if (a == b) std::cout << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

Тут уже не выведет сообщение. Почему так выходит?

Comment: Строковые литералы могут перекрываться в памяти. Такое сравнение `"Hello world" + 6 == "world"` запросто может вернуть [как `true`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6868cf413ce2623e), так [и `false`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1588e08230e01fcb). Точный результат такого сравнения не специфицируется. См.: [lex.string/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возьмем, например, Visual C++ 2019 и скомпилируем первый код

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char* a = (char*)"string";
    char* b = (char*)"string";
    if (a == b) std::cout << "Hello world";
}
```

следующим образом:

```
cl /EHsc test.cpp
```

Результат — никакого вывода на экран... Добавим ключик `/GF`:

```
cl /EHsc /GF test.cpp
```

и получим приветствие. И первое, и второе поведение вполне допустимы, потому что стандарт ничего не говорит о том, где именно хранятся строковые литералы. Даже не надо все эти переменные и приведения, достаточно кода

```
std::cout << ("a" == "a");
```

Так что в определенном смысле *вопрос основан на неверной посылке*... По сути, основываясь на представлении о равенстве/неравенстве указателей двух строковых литералов мы получаем в некотором смысле неопределенное поведение (не говоря уж об UB, вызванном приведением строкового литерала к типу `char*`).

А вот во втором случае дела обстоят совсем иначе, потому что здесь

```
char a[] = "string";
char b[] = "string";
```

имеются два **разных** массива в памяти, а строка — не более чем инициализатор... Изменяя содержимое `a`, вы никак не меняете тем самым содержимое `b`. Так что и адреса их различны.

Comment: Поздравляю с +200К репы!

Comment: Здесь нет UB: ни в сравнении указателей (это [unspecified](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#9) поведение) ни в касте (плох не каст, а изменение литерала с его помощью).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Соглашусь не глядя — я эту разницу между UB и UB не очень четко чувствую. Главное - стараться избегать и того, и другого... :)

Comment: Undefined - это то, чего нельзя делать, потому что эффект может быть непредсказуемый и плохой. А для unspecified (всегда?) обозначены варианты того, что может произойти. Т.е. `"a" == "a"` вернет либо true, либо false, и не будет никаких странных крашей и странных оптимизаций компилятора. Есть еще третий термин, implementation-defined behavior - это как unspecified, но дополнительно компилятор обязан задокументировать свое поведение.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это по последствиям. А вот по причинам... есть какие-то темные углы, которые никак не даются для ясного и четкого понимания во всех тонкостях. Никак не удается справиться со strict aliasing, выравниванием и запомнить все причины UB :) Впрочем, с UB полегче, тут все же есть какое-то логическое обоснование...

Answer (score 4):

Строковые литералы с одинаковым текстом могут иметь одинаковые адреса, а могут и не иметь - это зависит от компилятора.

> [`[lex.string]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#9)
>
> Whether all string-literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.

А во втором примере вы сравниваете не литералы, а обычные массивы, созданные из них. На них (как и на остальные объекты) это исключение не действует, и они обязаны иметь разные адреса.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в первом примере вы присваиваете так называемый строковый литерал "string" в указатель, причём два раза в разные указатели. У вас два указателя ссылаются на один и тот же литерал. Во втором примере вы создаёте массив из char'ов, а под него компилятором выделяется статическая память, куда данная строка копируется.